# Dividing map into features (whole squares)

Tags: qgis, features, vector-grid

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0. I divided a map of a state with its municipalities into many features using a GRID (small squares), but instead of creating one ID per feature (one ID per square), it creates one ID per feature considering also the features divided by the municipalities lines, which I don´t want. I mean if a square is divided by the borderline between two municipalities, it considers two features.  I would like to have the map of the state with its municipalities divided into many "whole" squares, and each and every one of those squares should have one unique ID. Could anyone help me?

Comment: How does this work if the municipalities are non-square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use, instead as a municipalities map, a STATE map only to get the state divided into a grid,

then overlay the new state-wide grid with the municipal data, perhaps???

Comment: ok ill try it, but what do you mean with overlay?